# Changes in a git commit are back with no record

Tags: git, github

I deleted lines from 4 files, added the changed files, committed the changes, and kept working, going on to make more changes and commit several more times. I realize later that the lines I deleted in that original commit came back in the very next commit; however I did not change them back and there is no record of the lines being re-added when I view future commit logs on GitHub.

- **commit #n** - Current
- **more commits...**
- **commit #2** - Those deleted lines are back with no record in the commit
- **commit #1** - I deleted lines from 4 files

I have already done a pull request before noticing the problem, so I'm unsure of how to fix this problem. Making the change and committing again seems sloppy and wrong; not to mention I would like to understand how this can happen so I can avoid this in the future.

Also, when I "browse files" on GitHub, the files that were changed in that commit still have the original commit reference for those files. What gives?!

Comment: You staged the file (with 4 deleted lines) `git add editedFileWith4Lines`?

Comment: Yes, and when I view that commit it shows the changes. I edited the original post to clarify that.

Comment: Are you the only user of this repository? When no, maybe somebody else pushed the original files.

Comment: I am not the only user, but I am definitely the only one who has made any commits or pushes since the commit in question. The only other person who contributes to it is sitting next to me and is as confused as I am.

Comment: Are you using `git diff --cached` to see the changes before you commit?  See `git log -S"my deleted line"`  to find the commits that added or deleted these lines.

Comment: @Gregg I don't always use diff --cached when I commit, if that's what you mean, but I did just use it retrospectively and saw nothing aside from the line deletions I made during that commit.
`git log -S "my deleted line"` also showed that nothing affected those lines after the commit in which I deleted them.

Comment: It's really pretty simple here: what you're describing didn't happen.  `git add` adds the current content of the file.  The only way content shows up in a commit is if you `git add` and then `git commit` it.

Comment: @jthill I definitely did use `git add` and `git commit`. When I view the changes for that specific commit on the GitHub website, it shows the deleted lines as changes. At the top of the commit page it says: "Showing  **4 changed files**  with **0 additions and 12 deletions.**" I've been using git for 2 years and I've never seen this happen before.

Comment: Possibly helpful: output from `git log --graph --decorate --oneline --all`, snipped down to regions surrounding the areas where things are good and then go bad.

Comment: @torek thanks for sharing that command, that's very useful. So, the specified commit is only 4 commits behind HEAD right now, which makes it very easy to see that nothing went off the branch path there. Just a straight line to the current pull request merge. Again, I checked every commit log on GitHub since that one and there is no evidence of those lines being added back.

Comment: Are any of them merge commits? `git log -p` *skips* the diffs for merge commits by default (you must request either combined diffs, or `-m` split diffs, for merge commits, to see what happened inside them).

Comment: You can use `git blame` to show you which commit appears to have introduced the most recent version of those lines... In other news, scenarios like this are prime arguments for the "one repo per user" philosophy, and its immediate corollary - "one user per repo"...

Comment: Well, to my embarrassment, the problem was with a 5th file that I was looking at that missed the change. Which makes sense because changes don't magically disappear. So now do I delete this question, since it's not really valid? I must admit I did learn something in the comments, but does that justify leaving the question up?

Comment: lol fyi been there. no, I'll vote to close ~problem went away~.